# Nethereum listen to an event after send transaction

Tags: solidity, transactions, addresses, nethereum, c#

Solidity code for creating a new contract calling createRainfallPolicy:

```
event PolicyCreated(address _policy, string _insuredId);
```

```
function createRainfallPolicy(/*Params*/) public {
    RainfallPolicy policy = new RainfallPolicy(/*Args*/);
    emit PolicyCreated(address(policy), _insuredId);
}
```

.Net code for calling createRainfallPolicy:

```
var transactionInput = createPolicyFunction.CreateTransactionInput(account.Address, gas, null, null, params);
var transactionHash = await web3.Eth.TransactionManager.SendTransactionAsync(transactionInput);
```

It works as expected but I **need** to get the **address of the created contract** (RainfallPolicy address).